# Stuck on Recursive Pattern in Java (ZigZag)

Tags: java

Language: Java

I'm having issues with a recursive method that is supposed to produce the following pattern:

```
Zigzag 1
*

Zigzag 2
*
**
 *

Zigzag 3
*
***
 *

Zigzag 4
*
**
 *
****
  *
  **
   *

Zigzag 6
*
***
 *
******
   *
   ***
    *

Zigzag 8
*
**
 *
****
  *
  **
   *
********
    *
    **
     *
    ****
      *
      **
       *
```

---

This is what I have so far:

```
public void printZigZag(int size, int indent) {
    if(size > 0 && indent >= 0){
        String temp = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < indent; i++){
            temp += " ";
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            temp += "*";
        }


        printZigZag(size/2, indent);

        /* Example of something I've tried...
                    if(size != 1){
            indent++;
        }

        if(size % 2 != 0){
            indent = temp.length() - 2;
        } else {
            indent = temp.length() / 2;
        }
        */

        System.out.println(temp);
        printZigZag(size/2, ++indent);
    }
}
```

---

But that code produces this (Where Zigzag # is the size):

```
Zigzag 1
*

ZigZag 2
*
**
 *

ZigZag 3
*
***
 *

ZigZag 4
*
**
 *
****
 *
 **
  *

ZigZag 6
*
***
 *
******
 *
 ***
  *

ZigZag 8
*
**
 *
****
 *
 **
  *
********
 *
 **
  *
 ****
  *
  **
   *
```

I've been working on this for a few days now, with all kinds of different if's and ordering of statements and can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

Really appreciate any help that can be given, thank you in advance.

PS. Sorry for the huge post.

Comment: "supposed to produce the following pattern:" - can I ask, is this from a textbook, online tutorial?

Comment: You don't have to pass an indentation factor. The top part is not indented, the bottom part is indented by n/2 spaces.

Comment: @AndrewMartin This is from a textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks the recursion pattern is:

```
zigZag(1): print *
zigZag(n): zigZag(n / 2), print n times *, zigZag(n / 2)
```

Just pay attention to the indentation factor. Try this:

```
public class ZigZag {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 4;

        zigZag(n, 0);
    }

    public static void zigZag(int n, int i /* indentation factor */) {
        if(n > 1)
            zigZag(n / 2, i);

        for(int k = i; k > 0; k--)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for(int k = n; k > 0; k--)
            System.out.print("*");

        System.out.println();

        if(n > 1)
            zigZag(n / 2, i + n / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the second zigZag(n/2) is indented by n/2 spaces.

Comment: PS. it looks you have to shift properly accordingly to n when you recurse after printing the asterisks, so printZigZag(size/2, indent + size /2); and not printZigZag(size/2, ++indent);

Comment: Works great, I tried pretty much the same thing except I had it passing size/2(or n/2) for the indent instead since my testing program only passes 0's for the indent. I see now why that was such a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don't mind, I couldn't resist :) Here's it implemented in JS.

```
function zigzag(n, pad) {
  if(n > 0) {
    zigzag(~~(n / 2), pad);
    console.log(Array(pad+1).join(" ") + Array(n+1).join("*"));
    zigzag(~~(n / 2), pad+~~(n / 2)); //~~ implicitily coerces floats to whole numbers
  }
}

zigzag(1, 0);
zigzag(2, 0);
zigzag(3, 0);
zigzag(4, 0);
```

Comment: @VaheHarutyunyan Which browser are you on?

Comment: Well, it matters to me; I use Javascript extensively nowadays and I'm interested to know when, and why is it failing. So I'll kindly ask again, how did you test this?